# Update Data Extension in Parent BU when Data Extension in Child BU gets updated( move data from Child BU to Parent

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sfmc-business-unit

Can someone please help me with this scenario?

I have a data extension in Child Business Unit and the same data extension in Parent Business Unit. The Child Business Unit gets updated randomly and I want the parent unit to get updated when ever the child unit is got updated.

How can I acheive this ?

** Note (We  are using Enterprise 1.0 Business unit which means we don't have shared data extensions feature available )**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Marketing Cloud SFTP, you could create an automation in Child BU, that would export all the data from your DE to FTP, and another automation in Parent BU, that would import this file from FTP and update the data in your DE in Parent BU.
This wouldn't be possible in real-time though, you could automate it to run every hour or so.
Check out the [Marketing Cloud SFTP Guide](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_enhanced_ftp_guide.htm&type=5) and [Automation Studio](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_automation_studio.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @SalesforceUser if my answer helped, please mark it as accepted - thank you!